# Setting an Fcgid Directive produces an Invalid Command error

Tags: apache-2.2, php5, mod-fcgid

I'm trying to set the `MaxRequestInMem`, `MaxRequestsPerProcess` and `MaxRequestLen` but it keeps on saying that it's an `Invalid command 'MaxRequestInMem', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`.

I put this directive inside `<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>`.

I also tried loading the mod_fcgid.so module in httpd.conf as so:

`LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so`

and it actually gives a warning saying that `module fcgid_module is already loaded, skipping`

I tried changing the directives from the old name to the new name (`FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess`) and it still says that it's an invalid command.

Has anyone else experienced this strange behavior?

By the way, I'm receiving an error saying `(104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request function` so it seems to me that mod_fcgid is loaded/being used. And it's also the reason why I want to set those directives. I just don't get it why it won't recognize the directives though.

What should I do to be able to set those directives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It already loaded

it means , you have LoadModule  include multiple conf file. , Please check all included conf file .

I tried changing the directives from the old name to the new name (FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess) and it still says that it's an invalid command.

It possible to version support.

Comment: so what can I do to be able to set those directives?

Comment: Ok, I just figured that we have a very old version of mod_fcgid. We have to update, then. Thanks for the answer.